# Como remover um array, a partir de ocorrência encontrada dentro de um sub array!

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Bom, tenho a seguinte situação, precisaria verificar se o termo existe (nome das frutas) se sim deletar o array que esta acoplando os valores (nome da fruta e código)

exemplo: Ao buscar pelo termo abacaxi fazer isso

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => maça
        [1] => 1256
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => abacaxi
        [1] => 1234
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => pera
        [1] => 235
    )
```

virar isso

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => maça
            [1] => 1256
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => pera
            [1] => 235
        )
```

Não consegui fazer funcionar com array multidimensional! Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supondo que `$frutas` seja o array alvo da consulta seguida de exclusão:

```
$frutas = [
  ['maça', 1256],
  ['abacaxi', 1234],
  ['pera', 235],
  ['banana', 1235],
  ['laranja', 2135],
  ['limão', 2315],
  ['morango', 2351]
];
```

Uma possibilidade é filtrar o array com [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) e verificar cada elemento com [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php) para saber se um de seus valores é a string de corte.

```
$frutas = array_filter($frutas, function ($item){
  return !in_array('abacaxi', $item);
});
```

Outra possibilidade é iterar com [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) por cada elemento do array e destruir com [`unset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php) o elemento possua a string de corte:

```
foreach($frutas as $key => &$value){
  if (in_array('pera', $value)) unset($frutas[$key]);
}
```

Teste ambos os exemplos no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/WhitesmokePunctualDebugmonitor

Comment: Obrigado meu caro deu super certo!

Comment: Olá, implementando no meu projeto, pude perceber que a primeira solução não funciona com variáveis contendo o valor de busca, apenas digitando a string diretamente, sabe o motivo?

Comment: @CaioLourençon, tem como colocar um exemplo do problema que mencionou para eu poder analisar. Pode ser um link para um arquivo de texto ou um sandbox online. Pois os dois exemplos usam o mesmo código como base `in_array()`.

Comment: editado, confere por favor!

Comment: @CaioLourençon a variável `$val_busca` não foi declarada dentro do escopo do callback. Basta a declarar como global dentro do callback `global $val_busca;` Veja o exemplo funcionando: https://repl.it/repls/LuxuriousNeatExpertise

Comment: Vou reverter a pergunta, pois a edição da pergunta transformou minha resposta numa coisa sem sentido.

Comment: parabéns, funcionando perfeitamente como precisava.

Comment: Se quiser adicionar essa implementação no seu comentário da solução, também acharia bom, pois creio que as pessoas utilizarão variáveis para busca.

Comment: @CaioLourençon eu agradeço a sugestão, mas vou declinar pois sai do foco original da questão e depois de respondida o formato do site não permite a mudança de escopo da pergunta, por isso a reverti, e também não permite assuntos divergentes da questão original. No caso eu apresentei a solução por cortesia, mas orientação correta seria lhe indicasse fazer uma nova pergunta e lincar essa como contexto.

Comment: vai lá meu caro retribuo a cortesia, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/448152/fu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-encontra-e-remover-termo-no-array-n%c3%a3o-funciona-com-variav%c3%a9l