# Fução para encontra e remover termo no array não funciona com variavél!

Tags: php, foreach, array-multidimensional

implementando em meu projeto a solução do usuário [Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques) na questão :

[Como remover um array, a partir de ocorrência encontrada dentro de um sub array!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/448047/como-remover-um-array-a-partir-de-ocorr%c3%aancia-encontrada-dentro-de-um-sub-array/448054?noredirect=1#comment859862_448054)

Me deparei com a situação de não estar conseguindo fazer a busca por valores armazenados em variáveis, somente funciona inserindo strings diretamente! Segue código.

```
$arr_val=array('abacaxi','limão');

// array para ser modificado
$frutas = [
  ['maça', 1256],
  ['abacaxi', 1234],
  ['pera', 235],
  ['laranja', 2135],
  ['limão', 2315],
  ['morango', 2351]
];

//laço para testar cada valor do array "$arr_val" e remover

foreach($arr_val as $val_busca){
  $frutas = array_filter($frutas, function ($item){
// aqui o valor de cada fruta a ser encontrado "$val_busca" não funciona por variavél
    return !in_array($val_busca, $item);
  });
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($frutas);echo"</pre>";
```

Agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa trazer a variável `$val_busca` para dentro do escopo da função, ou então você não irá poder acessa-la:

```
foreach($arr_val as $val_busca){
  $frutas = array_filter($frutas, function ($item) use ($val_busca) {
    return !in_array($val_busca, $item);
  });
}
```

Esse tipo de tratamento geralmente é necessário em linguagens que fazem o gerenciamento de memória com ARC, como é o caso do PHP, pois se a função não rodar de forma sincrona, o espaço na memória dessa variável poderia ser liberado antes da sua função de callback poder utilizar-la.

Comment: correto, definindo $val_busca como global dentro do escopo resolveu o problema!

Comment: @CaioLourençon essa abordagem é mais eficiente que declarar um global pois no exemplo sim um global funciona, mas caso no futuro você deseje encapsular esse procedimento em uma função/método ou se transformar o filtro em um código assíncrono o global deixa de funcionar.

Comment: Blz, vou seguir recomendações.